# Automate swipeable bottom sheet using Appium

Tags: appium, appium-android

Trying to automate the swipeable bottom sheet but the popup elements are not able to locate. Anyone has a solution to how to automate swipeable bottom popup. "close" button is not able to locate.

[Image of UiAutomator]

[image]

Comment: Swipeable bottom sheet sample https://manufont.github.io/react-swipeable-bottom-sheet/controlled.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking two questions, so here we go.

1. how to automate swipeable bottom popup

   The easiest way to automate the popup appearing is to click the Open button. But I guess you actually want to drag the button up.

   A java demo:

```java
WebElement srcEl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Controlled bottom sheet']"));  

TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
// Change the coordinate position according to your actual situation
action.longPress(srcEl).moveTo(100,100).release().perform();
```

More infomation: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions

2. "close" button is not able to locate

   The close button can not be found until the bottom sheet showing, so you should wait it, then locate the button.
   [image]

Comment: In addition, I have a small question. The sample is a web page, why do you use Appium instead of Selenium